# breeze.js - how coupled are the client and server versions

Tags: version, breeze, upgrade, server

I have a SPA that uses breeze on the client, and also using the .Net wepapi2/EF6 server libraries.  My current version for the client library is :

version:"1.4.6"
metadataVersion:"1.0.5"

The server DLL's have varying version #'s but were installed with the client lib at the same time, so pretty sure they're in sync.

I would like to upgrade the client version to 1.5.3 but not touch the server.  Mainly because the server side is all compiled DLL's and if there's any code that breaks during the upgrade, it will be much harder to find/debug the DLL code compared to the client JS that I can see/debug/modify realtime.

So my question is, how coupled are the client/server versions?  Can I keep my current server libs and upgrade the client only?

If I did decide to upgrade both, is there anything I should be aware of going from 1.4.6 to 1.5.3 in both the JS and .Net environments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our recommendation is usually to upgrade both at the same time.  In general, we very rarely have breaking changes on the server.  ( None in recent memory). But we do occasionally on the client and these are called out in the release notes ( available on the website here: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/release-notes.)  Most of these breaking changes are pretty subtle and you are unlikely to ever see one, but...

What does happen occasionally is that we add a new feature to the client that requires some additional code on the server.  But this would be unlikely to break anything unless you use the new client feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Jay.  Will back up everything and upgrade both components.

Comment: Note that the .NET server-side change in 1.5.x is [Support for ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/release-notes) versus WebAPI 2.1 in the 1.4.x version.  If you don't want to move to WebAPI 2.2, stick with your current breeze server version.